# Can you run percona tools with MYSQL REPLICATION without running a percona forked version of 5.5 MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, centos, percona

Currently running:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, 
for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

on CentOS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

I Successfully installed the percona toolkit

http://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/percona-toolkit/LATEST/percona-toolkit-2.1.8-1.noarch.rpm

and ran a successful command against the database:

```
pt-table-checksum --replicate=percona.checksums  --host=localhost --user=root --password=XYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Percona Toolkit is an independent set of tools and they work with Percona Server, MySQL and MariaDB as well